# Prove that an immersion is minimal

Tags: differential-geometry

If we have an immersion from $R^{2}\to R^{4}$, given by $(x,y)\to (x,y,x,y)$, how can we prove that the given immersion is minimal or not. Suppose that we choose $\{e_{1}, e_{2}\}$ for basis of $R^{2}$ and $\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}=Je_{1},e_{4}=Je_{2}\}$ for basis of $R^{4}$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This particular immersion has a plane as its image. Using the area form of the plane, one can show that the surface is minimal by the "calibration" method.